# Android - Webview only applying headers to initial request

Tags: android, webview

I'm writing an android app that uses webview to request content from a web server, but using mWebView.loadUrl(url1, headers); will only apply the headers to the initial request and not the resources in the request.

Any idea as so how to apply the headers to the resource requests as well?

Comment: +1 @stotherd did you get any solution to this problem I am stuck with this too and was not able to find solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to request the resources individually separately, and then did not complete the project.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure but you can try to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method and handle all redirects by starting `mWebView.loadUrl(url, yourHeaders);`
Dont forget to return true in that overriden method.

Comment: can you elaborate this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say that i can't believe that webview sucks so much.

This is what i did to pass custom headers

```
public class CustomWebview extends WebView {



    public void loadWithHeaders(String url) {

        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
            //makes a custom http request, which allows you to add your own headers
            return customRequest(url);
        }
      });

        loadUrl(url);
    }


    /**
    * Custom http request with headers
    * @param url
    * @return
    */
    private WebResourceResponse customRequest(String url) {

    try {

        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url.trim())
                .addHeader("Header-Name",  "Android Sucks")
                .build();

        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        return new WebResourceResponse(
                "text/html", // You can set something other as default content-type
                "utf-8",  // Again, you can set another encoding as default
                response.body().byteStream()
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
        return null;
    }
}
```

}